# FrontApp LiveChat integration in android - Webview not get hide as per guide

Tags: android, webview, frontapp

I am following this guide.

FrontApp, LiveChat ==> Opening the chat window directly with a custom button

https://dev.frontapp.com/docs/install-the-chat-widget-in-a-mobile-app#step-8-opening-the-chat-window-directly-with-a-custom-button

Problem is the webview not getting hide on chat dialog close, basically the my WebViewClient's shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not getting called.
I have double checked all the things and I am sure I have followed the guide correctly

code is also the same,
I have tested in Android 14, 13 emulator, its not working

Here is my activity code.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private var fileChooserResultLauncher = createFileChooserResultLauncher()
    private var fileChooserValueCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true)
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null)
        WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData()
        val webView = findViewById<View>(R.id.web) as WebView

        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
        webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true

        webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onShowFileChooser(
                webView: WebView?,
                filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
                fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?
            ): Boolean {
                try {
                    fileChooserValueCallback = filePathCallback
                    fileChooserResultLauncher.launch(fileChooserParams?.createIntent())
                } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    // Handle "No activity found to handle intent" error
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                return true
            }
        }

        val autoOpen =
            "<html>"+
                    "<body>" +
                    "<script src=\"https://chat.frontapp.com/v1/chat.bundle.js\"></script>" +
                    "<script>" +
                    "window.FrontChat('init', {chatId: 'ce4c58cd0f7cbcd3ed3eaf3b0b09XXXX', useDefaultLauncher: false, shouldMobileReloadOnClose: true})" +
                    "</script>" +
                    "<script>" +
                    "setTimeout(() => window.FrontChat('show'), 2000)" +
                    "</script>" +
                    "</body>" +
                    "</html>"

        

        webView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://localhost/", autoOpen, "text/html", "UTF-8", null)

        val openChatButton: Button = findViewById<View>(R.id.button) as Button

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                Log.e("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", "called")
                webView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                openChatButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                webView.reload()
                return false
            }
        }

        openChatButton.setOnClickListener {
            openChatButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            webView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    private fun createFileChooserResultLauncher(): ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> {
        return registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
            if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                fileChooserValueCallback?.onReceiveValue(arrayOf(Uri.parse(it?.data?.dataString)))
            } else {
                fileChooserValueCallback?.onReceiveValue(null)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also. Unfortunately no iOS guide is provided for this. How to do this is iOS anybody knows about, Anyways first thing first is make this work on Android